# WCF not required fileds

Tags: c#, wcf

This class was generated automatically .cs class from .xsd but I would like to make some of my fields are not required. This does not work "IsNullable", [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]:

WSDL

```
  <xs:element name="addrTypeCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="streetName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

.CS

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="example")]
public partial class Address {

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    private string addrTypeCode;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    private string streetName;

    /// <remarks/>
   [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string AddrTypeCode {
        get {
            return this.addrTypeCode;
        }
        set {
            this.addrTypeCode = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string StreetName {
        get {
            return this.streetName;
        }
        set {
            this.streetName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the xsd doesn't match the generated code definition.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Where is your OperationContract and your DataContract. Are you sure this has anything at all to do with WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another problem in application all things work correct.